# swf file size issue in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, flash

I have swf file, the firefox and chrome displays the swf files as per the mentioned width and height. But in Internet explorer, the swf file is too small than the other browsers.

Any idea to fix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In "object" if you delete attribute "class" then you'll have normal size in IE,opera,ff. In Chrome will be smaller.

Answer (score 1):

In IE8, the common fix was to set up IE7 emulation with a meta-data tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Not sure if that will fix your issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know which method you are using to embed your swf file into your html page, I would advise you to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

It is an open source javascript class that handles this kind of browser quirks for you.

Cheers